# IOS 5.0 jailbreak how to customize/block banner notifications

Tags: ios, notifications, jailbreak, customization, banner

I was wondering, what header/function I have to hook into to customize or block banner notifications in iOS 5? I have tried many functions so far but none of them seem to work anymore.

Any help is truly appreciated.

THX!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try hooking - (void)_presentBannerForItem:(id)arg1 method within SBBulletinBannerController. If you are using Theos, then the following code snippet should prevent the banner notification from being presented. For more control, look into other methods in this class

```
#import <SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h>

%hook SBBulletinBannerController

- (void)_presentBannerForItem:(id)arg1
{
    %log;

}
%end
```

Comment: Hey rajagp, thx for the response. I tried your suggestions but it doesn't do anything. I'm wondering if I have different header files for springboard. Instead of "arg1" as an argument, I have "item". Any way you can send me your springboard header files? that would be great !!